# Problems making a dynamic form with javascript and css: iding/showing fields dynamically doesn't work. Can You help me?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, dynamic, xhtml

please, I need help. I am writing my website and I need to create a "dynamic form". So I decided to do this using javascript.
I have a form with various fields. Two of them are two radio buttons. Their code is:

```
<input id="prog" type="radio" name="tipo" value="app" onClick="app();" tabindex="4"><label for="prog">Ad un'applicazione</label></input> 
<input id="website" type="radio" name="tipo" value="sito" onClick="sito();" tabindex="5"><label for="website">Ad un sito Web</label></input>
```

As you probably noticed, the two radio buttons have their event "onclick" associated with two javascript' functions. Their code is:

```
function app() {
app=document.getElementById("app");
sito=document.getElementById("sito");
app.style.display = "block";
sito.style.display = "none";
}

function sito() {
sito=document.getElementById("sito");
app=document.getElementById("app");
sito.style.display = "block";
app.style.display = "none";
}
```

And as you've probably understood, this javascript' code doesn't work. The first time I select one of the radio buttons it works perfectly; but after that, if I try to change the selection I receive an error (object property is not supported).
What I need to accomplish is simple (not for me, I don't know anything about javascript..I wrote this code after having a little reading of some tutorials):
- If the first radio button is selected, the content of the div with id "app" must be shown and the content of the div with id "sito" must be idden;
- If the second radio button is selected, the content of the div with id "sito" must be shown and the content of the div with id "app" must be idden;

By default, of course, the two divs are idden. Their css rule is:

```
#app, #sito{
display: none;
}
```

Is this the right way to get this result? Or can you suggest one better?
Can you help me to understand the reason why this script doesn't work? And can you tell me, please, how to fix it?

Sorry for the mystakes I did in this message, I am Italian...

```
   Vincenzo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its cause your function and your variables have the same name. Not using var defines the variables in the scope of window the same where your functions are declared in.

```
 //here you declare a function with the name app in the global namespace
    function app() {
    //here you override app with a dom element
    app=document.getElementById("app");
    sito=document.getElementById("sito");
    app.style.display = "block";
    sito.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Use var to hold the variables in the function in the scope of the function:

```
  //here you declare a function with name app in the global namespace
    function app() {
    //now you create a new var app in the scope of the function and dont override the app function
    var app=document.getElementById("app");
    var sito=document.getElementById("sito");
    app.style.display = "block";
    sito.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Btw you can also rename the function or your variables in the function, but its always better to use "var" to bound the variables to the scope of the function.